# save txt on array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code to read and print a .txt file

```
public static void main(String [] arg) {
  ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        try { 
              Scanner scan = new Scanner( new File("c:\\Ps.txt") ); 
              while( scan.hasNext() ) { 
                    lista.add( scan.nextLine() ); 
              } 
              scan.close(); 

        } 
        catch(Exception e) { 
              e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        String items[] = lista.toArray(new String[lista.size()]); 
        for(String item : items) { 
              System.out.println( item ); 



        } 
  }
```

the txt file format is this :
name,5,3,6,8,9

the name of the student and 5 grades, i need to put each file on an array to manipulate them

i need help to put them on an array

Comment: `lista.add(...);` Isn't that adding items to an arraylist...? I don't understand your problem here.

Comment: how can i put the like on the array like array(0)=name, array(1)=5, etc

Comment: Should be `hasNextLine`

Answer (score 0):

First, you must separate each line . You can do it using the [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, with regex being what separates each object:

```
String[] splits = item.split(","); //item's properties are separated by commas
```

This will return a `String` array with "name", "5", "3", "6", "8" and "9".

If you want to convert the grades to `int`s, you can do it with the [`Integer.parseInt(String integer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method:

```
for (int i = 1; i < splits.length; i++) { // i = 1 because the index 0 is for the name
    grades.add(Integer.parseInt(splits[i]));
}
```

PD: You can directly do this with the `Scanner`, using its [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) (for name) and [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) (for the grades) methods. To set the separator, use [`useDelimiter(String pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use String Class split() method to get the grade and marks into a string array like below:

```
      for(String item : items) { 
          String[] details = item.split(",");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] arg) {
    ArrayList<String[]> lista = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
    try { 
         Scanner scan = new Scanner( new File("c:\\Ps.txt") ); 
         while( scan.hasNext() ) { 
              // This will split the line into a 6 element string array.
              // { name, grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5 }
              lista.add(scan.nextLine().split(",", -1));
         } 
         scan.close();
    } 
    catch(Exception e) { 
          e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

You can access the name the grades belong to by using...

```
lista.get(0)[0]
```

You could access grade 4 of an entry by using...

```
Integer.parseInt(lista.get(0)[4]);
```

Of course you will need to ensure proper formatting of the file before this code can run as it does not check each line for formatting.